Django on IIS with FastCGI: HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error (Config Error 0x8007000d)
I'm trying to host a Django application on IIS using FastCGI. I've followed the steps to set up IIS with FastCGI and the wfastcgi.py handler for Django. However, I keep encountering an HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error with error code 0x8007000d.
The error message doesn't give much detail, except for stating that "the related configuration data for the page is invalid" and that there might be an issue with the web.config file. Below is the content of my web.config file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <!-- FastCGI Handler Configuration for Django -->
        <handlers>
            <add name="FastCGIHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule"
                 scriptProcessor="C:\Users\administrator.MERITMILL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe|C:\Users\administrator.MERITMILL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py"
                 resourceType="File" requireAccess="Script" />
        </handlers>

        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".ttf" mimeType="application/x-font-ttf" />
        </staticContent>

        <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" existingResponse="PassThrough" />
        <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
        <tracing>
            <traceFailedRequestsLogging enabled="true" directory="C:\inetpub\logs\FailedReqLogFiles" />
        </tracing>
    </system.webServer>

    <appSettings>
        <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\materials" />
        <add key="DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE" value="material_management.settings" />
        <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="django.core.wsgi.get_wsgi_application" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>

Hhere’s what I’ve done so far:
Installed FastCGI and WFastCGI:
Followed the installation process and verified the wfastcgi.py handler is correctly located and mapped in IIS.
Set up FastCGI handler in web.config:
Configured it to point to my Python312 executable and the wfastcgi.py handler file.
Web.config Configuration:
I've ensured the paths are correct and that there are no duplicate entries for mimeMap. I’ve also tried simplifying the web.config as much as possible to avoid conflicts.
Permissions:
Ensured that IIS_IUSRS has read permissions for the web.config, wfastcgi.py, and the Python interpreter.
ApplicationHost.config:
Verified that the applicationHost.config file has the proper FastCGI settings and mappings for Python.
Error Code Variations:
Initially, I received error 0x800700b7 (duplicate mimeMap entry) for .css and .woff, but I resolved that by removing duplicates.
Currently, I am encountering error code 0x8007000d for an invalid configuration, but I am not sure what is wrong with the web.config.
I expect IIS to forward requests to the Django app via FastCGI without configuration errors. The application should serve content without throwing HTTP 500 errors.
What I'm asking:

Is there anything specific in my configuration (especially the web.config) that could be causing this issue?

Could the issue be related to how FastCGI and Django work together on IIS?

Are there any known steps or configurations I might be missing when deploying a Django app via FastCGI on IIS?



WFastCGI is no longer maintained, https://docs.lextudio.com/blog/running-django-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/

You need more information to analyze your problem, try using failed request tracing to see details about 500.19 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.
